# How to measure detailed battery performance in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, battery

I am using

```
Ubuntu 11.4 
gnome3
2.6.38-8-generic
```

I have just inserted a new battery. However, there is no settings that show the capacity current charge time, etc.

When I click the battery icon. All I get is the current percentage.

Is there anything that will give me more details about my battery?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 0):

Left click over battery icon -> click over "Laptop Battery X:XX left" text

In "Power statistics" you have the details you´re looking for.
In "History" tab you can find charge and discharge profile graphics